# sending mail using javamail getting authentication issue

Tags: jakarta-mail

When I tried to send mail using following code, I got authentication issues.

Here's my code:

```
    public class NewSendMail {

    String to = "********";
    String subject = "subject";
    String msg ="email text....";
    final String from ="*******";
    final  String password ="******";


    public NewSendMail(){

    }

    public boolean sendMymail(){

        Properties props = new Properties();  
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");     
        props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");  
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");  
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");  
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");  
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");  
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");  
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,  
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
                return new PasswordAuthentication(from,password);  
            }  
        });  

//      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

        //session.setDebug(true);  
        Transport transport;
        InternetAddress addressFrom = null;
        try {
            transport = session.getTransport();
            addressFrom = new InternetAddress(from);
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
            message.setSender(addressFrom);  
            message.setSubject(subject);  
            message.setContent(msg, "text/plain");  
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));  
            transport.connect();  
            Transport.send(message);  
            transport.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  



        return true;
    }  


}
```

It is throwing a `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException`.

How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The following code may help you

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class Email {

 private static String USER_NAME = "username";  // GMail user name (just the part before "@gmail.com")
 private static String PASSWORD = "password"; // GMail password

 private static String RECIPIENT = "xxxxx@gmail.com";

public static void main(String[] args) {
String from = USER_NAME;
String pass = PASSWORD;
String[] to = { RECIPIENT }; // list of recipient email addresses
String subject = "Java send mail example";
String body = "hi ....,!";

sendFromGMail(from, pass, to, subject, body);
}

 private static void sendFromGMail(String from, String pass, String[] to, String subject, String body) {
Properties props = System.getProperties();
String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", host);
props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");


Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

try {


    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

    // To get the array of addresses
    for( int i = 0; i < to.length; i++ ) {
        toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
    }



    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setText(body);


    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");


    transport.connect(host, from, pass);
    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();

}
catch (AddressException ae) {
    ae.printStackTrace();
}
catch (MessagingException me) {
    me.printStackTrace();
  }
  }
 }
```

This code worked for me, If it is not working for you, Check your jar files

Answer (score 0):

I tell everyone who asks for JavaMail help the same things.  (I wonder why they call it a [FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html)?)

Fix these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Follow [this example for Gmail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).

Turn on [session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) to get more details of what's going wrong, and post the output if you still can't figure it out.

Either you're sending the wrong username or password, or the server is rejecting your login attempt for other reasons, perhaps because you haven't enabled [less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps).